# Setting log level to logging.DEBUG or logging.INFO has no effect

Tags: python, logging, python-3.6

I am trying to do a pretty simple logging setup. I just want all of my log output to go to the terminal and to my log file. I found the below example on [Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-logging/) that demonstrates the setup of stream and file log handlers:

```
# logging_example.py

import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
c_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.warning('This is a warning')
logger.error('This is an error')

## Log Output
# 2019-08-31 22:16:02,478 - __main__ - WARNING - This is a warning
# 2019-08-31 22:16:02,478 - __main__ - ERROR - This is an error
```

And this logs to the console and to the file as you would expect. However, when I modify the program so that it will also log INFO, like so:

```
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)


logger.warning('logs')
logger.error('logs')
logger.info('should log but doesn\'t')
logger.debug('should log but doesn\'t')

## Log Output
# __main__ - WARNING - logs
# __main__ - ERROR - logs
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will also need to invoke `setLevel(level)` on the `logger` object itself, as, by default, it will use `ROOT`'s logging level (if it doesn't have any other ancestors), which is `WARNING`:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Full code with output:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # <<< Added Line
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)


logger.warning('logs')
logger.error('logs')
logger.info('should log but doesn\'t')
logger.debug('should log but doesn\'t')
```

Output:

```
__main__ - WARNING - logs
__main__ - ERROR - logs
__main__ - INFO - should log but doesn't
__main__ - DEBUG - should log but doesn't
```

Comment: Ah hey that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is two place you can set level: `Logger` , `Handler`. both of them will affect the output of your logging setting -- in different node of the logging flow. also you can add `Fliter` to these two
instance to filter log record with more sophisticate rule.

flowing char in the [office docment](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial) make clear what happening when logging.
[image]