# Python logging: Why am not seing the INFO and DEBUG mnessages?

Tags: python, logging

When I run this code:

```
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__":
  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
  logger.info("INFO message")
  logger.debug("DEBUG message")
  logger.warning("WARNING message")
  logger.error("ERROR message")
```

I get the following output:

```
WARNING message
ERROR message
```

I come I don't see the INFO and DEBUG messages?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/48787538/11082165 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/57742985/11082165

Comment: Unduping. Neither the dupe target nor Brian's links explain what's going on here.

Comment: Found a better dupe target.

Comment: Just to note, you don't see a similar problem when you use the module-level functions `logging.info`, etc, because they implicitly call `logging.basicConfig` if no handlers are detected.